# ng-snotify, No notification appears on route change

Tags: angularjs, typescript, notifications, react-router

this.snotifyService.success('User is authenticated', 'Login Success', {
timeout: 2000,
showProgressBar: false,
closeOnClick: false,
pauseOnHover: true
});
this.router.navigate(['omanCargo/home']);

When i change the route after triggering the success message as shown nothing displays.
Any help will be appreciated, i am a newbie in angular 4

Comment: related: https://github.com/artemsky/ng-snotify/issues/23

Answer (score 3):

did you **import the CSS** somewhere?
You should import one of this in your global style.scss like this

```
@import "~ng-snotify/styles/material";
```

or

```
@import "~ng-snotify/styles/material.css";
```

if you using css syntax.

if you using css syntax and angular-cli. Import styles directly in .angular-cli.json

```
{
  "styles": [
          "../node_modules/ng-snotify/styles/{STYLE_NAME}.css",
          "styles.css"
  ]
}
```

**Also *make sure* you put**

```
<ng-snotify></ng-snotify>
```

somewhere near the root of your application, I put mine in my home.component.ts